# No line connect in point

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image: Here's the image of my problem]

I want to have a line to connect the points here.

Here is the code I have used:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)
```

```
# Create a line chart with markers
ggplot(df, aes(x = USER_ALLIAS , y = AVERAGE_HEART_RATE)) +
  geom_line(color = "blue", linetype = "solid") +
  geom_point(color = "blue") +
  geom_line(aes(y = MAXIMUM_HEART_RATE), color = "red") +
  geom_point(aes(y = MAXIMUM_HEART_RATE), color = "red") +
  #Connect the points
  geom_path(aes(x = USER_ALLIAS, y = AVERAGE_HEART_RATE), color = "blue", linetype = "sold") +
  geom_path(aes(x = USER_ALLIAS, y = MAXIMUM_HEART_RATE), color = "red") +
  labs(title = "Average and Maximum Heart Rate per User", x = "User ID", y = "Heart Rate") `
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  With no data and no plot, it's difficult to see your problem!

Comment: Hello! I have just attached the image of my problem to see it. Thank you.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that your `USER_ALLIAS` is character.  That means `ggplot2` is treating it as a factor and so there is only a single point in each group, and thus nothing to "join up" when drawing the lines.  Convert your user ids to numerics and adjust the labelling of the x axis if necessary.

Comment: Incidentally, your data is not tidy, which is making your life more difficult than it needs to be.  `ggplot2` as part of ther tidyverse, expects tidy data.  To make your data frame tidy, use `pivot_wider` to put `AVERAGE_HERAT_RATE` and ~MAXIMUM_HERT_RATE` in a single column and use a new column, `Type` say, to distinguish between the two summaries.  You can the use `aes(colour = Type)` to draw multiple lines in a single `geom_xxx` call.  Your code will be shorter, more rubust and easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: ... or set the `group` aesthetic, i.e. do `geom_line(aes(group = 1), color = "blue")` and `geom_line(aes(y = MAXIMUM_HEART_RATE, group = 1), color = "red")`

Comment: @stefan  true, though I believe that's treating the symptom not the underlying condition.

Comment: @Limey Reshaping to long is the easier way to create the plot. But we still have to use the `group` aes. And IMHO we are not treating any symptoms since from the perspective of tidy data the data is already tidy as the average and maximum are two different variables.